# Django JWT Auth for custom model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a custom user model

```
class User(models.Model):
    fields...
```

It also has a email, password field among other detail fields. I want to use the simplejwt JWT authorization which takes email and password as input and generates JWT Tokens. Most tutorials include creating a superuser and passing username password of the superuser to get the token, But I want to do this for my custom user model.

Comment: From your model, it is not clear how you have extended the django's default user model. Have you extended AbstractUser class to make your custom django user model?

Comment: No I haven't used AbstractUser.

Comment: @AyushSinha check out `Djoser` documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST implementation of Django authentication system. **DJOSER**

[Getting Started with Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

Also, you need a **MOD HEADER** which is an Extension in Chrome
[Add it from here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)

Once your `Django` project is up and running go to
`localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/` for creating `access token` by submitting `username` and `password` (ie: `POST` method)

once `access token` is created you need to set it in **MOD HEADER** in **Request Header**  and you are good to go.
it's a JSON web token that's why you need to prefix it with `JWT` and then `access token`

[image: A sample look]

Answer (score 0):

django-simple-jwt generates the access and refresh tokens through the [obtainTokenPairView](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation). This views calls the [authenticate function from django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users). Therefore if you have set up a custom user model following [django guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/), to use the email in place of the username, django-simple-jwt should work out of the box

Otherwise, you still have the option to create your own view and [Generate the tokens manually](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html)